# How to get the JSON string POSTed to a REST API using PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, json, rest, curl

I am posting a JSON string using curl to an API developed in PHP, but I am unable to get the JSON string in the webservice method.

Here is my client using curl:

```
$data = array("name" => "prachi", "age" => "24");                                                                    
$data_string = json_encode($data);                                                                                   

$ch = curl_init('http://server.com/rest/users');                                                                      
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");                                                                     
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);                                                                  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);                                                                      
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
    'Content-Type: application/json',                                                                                
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))                                                                       
);                                                                                                                   

$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

Here, `rest` is the name of the controller class, and `user` is the action inside that. So, inside the `user` method, how can I get the JSON string?

Comment: What error do you get ?

Answer (score 0):

Use $_POST to get your string i.e.
$_POST['name'] and $_POST['age']

Replace curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST") with curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);